# sudo systemct enable apache2

Tags: apache2

When I want to enable the *apache2* in VMWare workstation by:

```
$ sudo apt-get install apache2 apache2-utils

$ sudo systemctl enable apache2
```

Then I receive an error like this:

```
apache2.service is not a native service, redirecting to systemd-sysv-install
executing /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable apache2
```

I think this problem arise form host IP but I can't figure out what it is
what should I do?

Comment: What makes you think that it is an error message? It is not an error message; `systemctl` is just telling you what it does. Indeed, `apache2` is not a native `systemd` service, so `systemctl` calls a helper program to do the work. And by the way, normally after installation `apache2` is already enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an error. Apache2 on Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't provide a native systemd service file, so your command was redirected to systemd-sysv-install and it was successfully executed.